# ios NSDateComponents and 2 specific different dates returns same day component

Tags: ios, date, nsdatecomponents, days

Here is a code sequence that gives me some trouble:

```
NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", 
                   [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:CCCalendarUnits fromDate:date].day];
NSLog(@"%@ %@",title, [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:CCCalendarUnits fromDate:date]);
```

Where : 
`#define CCCalendarUnits                    NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit`

And 2 logs :
      for date : **2012-10-27 21:00:00 +0000**

```
2012-08-13 12:44:14.298 xxx[2561:207] 2012-10-27 21:00:00 +0000
2012-08-13 12:44:14.299 xxx[2561:207] 28 <NSDateComponents: 0x842fe00>
    Calendar Year: 2012
    Month: 10
    Day: 28
    Week (obsolescent): 44
    Weekday: 1
```

for date : **2012-10-28 21:00:00**

```
2012-08-13 12:44:14.299 365Quotes[2561:207] 2012-10-28 21:00:00 +0000
2012-08-13 12:44:14.300 365Quotes[2561:207] 28 <NSDateComponents: 0x82264a0>
        Calendar Year: 2012
        Month: 10
        Day: 28
        Week (obsolescent): 44
        Weekday: 1
```

You can notice that for both dates (2012-10-27 21:00:00 +0000 and 2012-10-28 21:00:00 +0000) day component is the same (28)?
Any help to figure out why this is happening?

Thanks